# Internal Case is automatically shared with external contact if "Contact Name" field is populated with the external contact

Tags: case, sharing

Internal case would be shared with an external user once that user has been added as the "Contact Name" on the case even though the intention was not to share the case with the external user. Is there a work around for this where by the "contact name" is populated with an external user yet the case is not shared with the external user?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the community user is a named license then you could use a case record type and criteria based sharing rules to control access to internal cases. If it is a Community Login license this will not be an option.

Comment: the user has a Partner Community license.

Comment: Ok great! You will need to ensure that the Org Wide Default security setting for Case object is private. You can then introduce a record type to your cases specific to internal and external cases. Then when enabling access for your Partner Community user you can use  criteria based sharing to only allow read access to the external case record type.

Comment: Other alternatives i have seen would be to keep the default setting to private for all cases and then insert the specific sharing rules for the community user with either apex or flow.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has added in the Case Sharing Settings a checkbox option "Grant site users access to related cases". Basically gives read access to the Case if you are the Case.Contact.
You can turn it off, and it will work for new records. But it does not recalculate the sharing for existing records. You have to enforce it if needed, removing Contact field from existing Cases and later adding them again.